# Start mongod service at system startup

Tags: mongodb, startup

I recently updated `mongodb`, and I run Linux Mint (an Ubuntu based system) and every time I start it up, i cannot use Robomongo because the service `mongod` is not automatically started; every time I need to open up a terminal and use

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Is there a way to start `mongod` automatically at system start?

Comment: `sudo systemctl enable mongod && sudo systemctl start mongod`

Comment: there's no systemctl on ubuntu (mint), I tried the equivalent

`sudo update-rc.d -f foo_service remove`

and

`sudo update-rc.d foo_service defaults`

that's strange, it works on reboot, but ater turning off the pc and restarting it the day after, it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either put the command in your /etc/bashrc script under and if condition i.e. if the mongod process is not already running, then start it.

Other way is to modify your /etc/rc.local and add the command to start mongod in that file. It will start at bootup.

Comment: at last I used the second option, since I opened `/etc/bash.bashrc` (I don't have a `bashrc` file) and I found it way too complex to edit. Thanks!

Comment: that's strange, it works on reboot, but ater turning off the pc and restarting it the day after, it doesn't work anymore. Don't know why!

Answer (score 52):

Use the following command to autostart mongodb when system start.

```
systemctl enable mongod.service
```

Comment: there's no systemctl on ubuntu (mint)

Comment: Works for debian

Comment: Yeah, but I asked for linux mint, not for debian.

Comment: I used this command but it seems run without any error message, however I typed "mongo" I got this error:MongoDB shell version v4.2.8
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-07-12T19:33:16.990+0430 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :

Comment: @PredatorX ```systemctl start mongod``` and after that: ```mongo```

Comment: @Don Diego I'm using ubuntu (mint), it has the `systemctl` command.

Comment: @Eric yeah thank you, I asked it 5 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Using crontab on Ubuntu 20 you can try this.

```
crontab -e
```

And input this as a crontab entry

> @reboot service mongod start